# Playing several audio files simultaneously

Tags: android, cordova, audio, cordova-plugins

I'm producing an app where I load and loop several audio files simultaneously.

I'm using Cordova and the native audio Plugin. Sadly as soon as I start to loop a second file the audio starts to crash.

I play normal mp3 produced from wavs with Miro converter. Is there anything I have to watch out for?

Update:

The issue could be resolved by using ogg. But it doesn't answer the question. Is mp3 just that much more resource intensive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was found by using ogg AND loading and looping the files sequentially. First loading the files one after another, then looping the files one after another. After that, no more problems were experienced.